# DatePicker in sqlite mvvm

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a UWP app in C # with SQLite.

The problem I have is with the datepicker, when DatetimeOffsetTimeConverter gives me an exception, if I remove the date 01/01/1001 (to make it out the correct date), the date of the DatePicker comes in another page, called Mypetpage. 
c#
private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
       var  selectedDate =Data1.Date.ToString();



        DataBaseHelper Db_Pet = new DataBaseHelper();
       if (txtnombre.Text != "" & txtchip.Text !="" & txtraza.Text !=""  & SelectedgeneroText !="" & txtcolor.Text != ""  )
        {
            Db_Pet.Insert(new Mascota(txtnombre.Text, txtchip.Text, txtraza.Text, SelectedgeneroText, txtcolor.Text, selectedDate));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Enter your pet");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

xaml

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Data1" Grid.Row="1"
       Date="{Binding someDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResour DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
    public void CreateDataBase(string DB_PATH)
    {
        if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
        {
            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Mascota>();
                conn.CreateTable<Clinico>();


            }
        }
    }

    protected async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var petstore = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Insert(Mascota objMascota)
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
        {
            conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {

                conn.Insert(objMascota);
            });
        }
    }

    public Mascota ReadMascota(int mascotaid)
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existmascot = conn.Query<Mascota>("select * from Mascota where Id =" + mascotaid).FirstOrDefault();
            return existmascot;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Mascota> ReadAllMascota()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
            {

                List<Mascota> myMascota = conn.Table<Mascota>().ToList<Mascota>();
                ObservableCollection<Mascota> MascotaList = new ObservableCollection<Mascota>(myMascota);
                return MascotaList;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    //borra todo

    public void DeleteAllMascota()
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
        {

            conn.DropTable<Mascota>();
            conn.CreateTable<Mascota>();
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }


    }


    public void DeleteMascota(int Id)
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existmascot = conn.Query<Mascota>("select * from Mascota where Id =" + Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existmascot != null)
            {
                conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    conn.Delete(existmascot);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception? Show code from datacontext

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'No se pudo encontrar el texto asociado a este código de error. Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter [Line: 81 Position: 24]'

Comment: Is it a typo `StaticResour`, shouldn't it be `StaticResource`?

Comment: Then as I can solve, the exception

Comment: <DatePicker
                        x:Name="Data1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                       Date="{Binding someDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>

Comment: If you daclared converter as resoure in that page use x:Key attribute as name

Comment: Also the code snippet about `DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter` please if you still have issue.

Answer (score 1):

### ## EDIT-1 ##

So, i've made up a quick sample for all the possible cases that can be used to resolve your issue. you can pick any one. 
You can copy paste the code into your new project and you'll be able to see it.

**The XAML**

```
<Page
x:Class="DateTimeBinding.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DateTimeBinding"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:ViewModels="using:DateTimeBinding.ViewModels"
xmlns:Converters="using:DateTimeBinding.Converters">

<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <Converters:DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter x:Key="DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Padding="10">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
            <Run Text="Scenario 1:" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <Run Text=" Using the DateTime Picker and simple backing property"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDateString,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
            <Run Text="Scenario 2:" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <Run Text=" Direct Element x:Bind"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <DatePicker x:Name="SelectDatePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SelectDatePicker.Date,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
            <Run Text="Scenario 3:" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <Run Text=" Using a Calender Picker control instead"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="CalenderPicker" Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CalenderPicker.Date,Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Please Note:** I've used `x:Bind` instead of legacy `Binding` for performance and you should prefer compile time binding too. Just not in case of a `TextBox` as `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not available in x:Bind. Prefer legacy binding there incase you want to bind in a `twoWay mode`.

**Your ViewModel:**

```
internal class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    /// <summary>
    /// Backing property for the Selected Date in the Date Picker.k
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The selected date.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return selectedDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Date != selectedDate.Date)
            {
                selectedDate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate));
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDateString));
            }
        }
    }

    public string SelectedDateString => SelectedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

This is a basic implementation of it. Personally I would prefer the scenario 3 or scenario 2, because of which I don't have to have any `ViewModel` Code. I've still done an **{x:bind}** in both the scenarios just to keep the supporting properties updated. They are not needed if going with scenario 2 or 3.

**Your Converter:**

```
 public class DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
                return new DateTimeOffset(date);
            }
            return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return dto.DateTime;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You won't need this as well if you go with scenario 3 or 2 but in that case you might want to use a DateFormatter converter which converts the entire DateTime to a more readable or desirable format.

### Old Guesswork

---

There might be a few things going wrong. We'll escalate gradually,

1. The Typing mistake of `StaticResouce`.
2. The Converter in not initialized in your App.xaml or your converter dictionary (`ResourceDictionary`).
3. This is an extension of the point 2, you can also initialize your converter on the page where your converter is being used.
4. If the Converter is declared (like `<converters:DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter x:Key="DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter"/>`) the key might be wrong.

Comment: Putting date = {Binding somDate, mode = TwoWay, converter = {StaticResourse DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}} porduce the exception

Comment: @user3682557 can you please share information on the exception?

Comment: The problem is I get 01/01/001 as I can solve this problem

Comment: can you please share a quick sample of the issue. it'll be alot quicker. I'll fix it for you

Comment: I am using SQLite I have deatepicker and on another page the text box.

Comment: When I choose the date on the DatePicker has to go out in the TextBlock

Comment: @user3682557 I've updated the answer. Please let me know if there is anything I can help you with. If not, consider marking my answer as correct and upvoting it :P

Comment: The problem is in the C # code part when I try integral with the SQLite

Comment: You could share a demo solution that just has the SQLite part and the data binding of the date time picker, which according to you is causing the issue and elaborate what exactly is going wrong. You gotta be explicit

Comment: Or you can share the SQLite code and how it's interacting with the datetime picker

Comment: DataBaseHelper Db_Pet = new DataBaseHelper();
           if (txtnombre.Text != "" & txtchip.Text !="" & txtraza.Text !=""  & SelectedgeneroText !="" & txtcolor.Text != ""  )
            {
                Db_Pet.Insert(new Mascota(txtnombre.Text, txtchip.Text, txtraza.Text, SelectedgeneroText, txtcolor.Text, selectedDate));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Enter your pet");
                await md.ShowAsync();
            }

Comment: @user3682557 I would advise you to share more details for eg: how is selectedDate defined? secondly does the viewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Consider editing the question and sharing the code there with proper formatting. Share the xaml for the DatePicker, the converter and the binded property along with the method that gets called and where you've written the code about the db

Comment: @user3682557 then you must remove the question or add self answer your question.